# Ruby hash: return keys with highest value

Tags: ruby, hash, maxby

I want to return a hash key/value pair based on max key value. I know `max_by` works, but it stops at the first result. How can I return all results in the event of a tie?

```
{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 3,
  baz: 3
}.max_by { |key, value| value }

#=> [:bar 3] # Only bar comes back, but baz also has a value of 3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do :

```
hash = {
         foo: 1,
         bar: 3,
         baz: 3
       }

hash.group_by { |_,value| value }.max_by { |key,_| key }.last
# => [[:bar, 3], [:baz, 3]]
```

Breaking of the above code :

```
hash.group_by { |_,v| v } 
# => {1=>[[:foo, 1]], 3=>[[:bar, 3], [:baz, 3]]}
hash.group_by { |_,v| v }.max_by { |k,_| k }
# => [3, [[:bar, 3], [:baz, 3]]]
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the `_` meant to be? Is it the `key`? Why not use `key`?

Comment: +1! Thank you. I was not aware of the `_`. Is it documented any where?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Yes it is.. But I need to search.. :)